# How to insert record in a record in another company?

Tags: insert, axapta, dynamics-ax-2012, x++

I all, 
I have to insert a new record in a Table.

I'm in Company "A" and I have to save a new record in Company "B", from code.
I know the function *crosscompany* *changecompany* , but I don't know how to use well.
Do you know how I do?

My code is :

```
MyTable table;

changeCompany("AnotherCompany")
ttsBegin;
select forUpdate table;
    table.Field1 = "A";
table.insert();
ttsCommit;
```

but I save in my current company again
Thanks all,

enjoy!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm using AX 2009, I assume it's quite the same in AX 2012:

```
changeCompany('yourCompany')
{
    ttsBegin;
    select forUpdate table;
    table.Field1 = "A";
    table.insert();
    ttsCommit;
}
```

Comment: Also make sure to null your table buffer, if you do it in a loop.